# Trouble loading rgdal in RStudio

Tags: r, gdal, rstudio

Why is `rgdal` failing to load in `RStudio` (0.94.110) but not in `R` (2.13.2)?

```
abarbour% R

R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)
```

[edited to remove extraneous info]

```
> library(rgdal)
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: sp
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.8.1, released 2011/07/09
Path to GDAL shared files: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Resources/gdal
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009, [PJ_VERSION: 470]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
```

But, in RStudio:

```
R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)
```

[again, edited]

```
> library(rgdal)
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: sp
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/abarbour/kook.processing/R/PACKAGES/rgdal/libs/x86_64/rgdal.so':
  dlopen(/Users/abarbour/kook.processing/R/PACKAGES/rgdal/libs/x86_64/rgdal.so, 6): Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'rgdal'
```

Anyone know why this is happening?  Is there some sort of `RStudio` default that I don't know about?

*Note that `rgdal` was installed using the following command, having already installed the KyngChaos ([GDAL Complete framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks)):*

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-gdal-config=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/unix/bin/gdal-config --with-proj-include=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/include --with-proj-lib=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/lib' rgdal_0.7-1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Did you already post on [RStudio support](http://support.rstudio.org/)? That is maybe the better place to ask this question.

Comment: Yes (http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/1064-loading-rgdal-fails), but I linked to this question since formatting is much easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Credit due to Josh from the `RStudio` support staff (see the [discussion](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/1064-loading-rgdal-fails)).*

From within `RStudio`:

```
> setRepositories()
```

[enter "1 2"]

```
> install.packages("rgdal")
> library(rgdal)
```

gives the normal load behavior:

```
> library(rgdal)
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: sp
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.8.0, released 2011/01/12
Path to GDAL shared files: /Users/abarbour/kook.processing/R/PACKAGES/rgdal/gdal
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009, [PJ_VERSION: 470]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: /Users/abarbour/kook.processing/R/PACKAGES/rgdal/proj
```